# Add values to a list inside a list Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a class like this.

```
public class CameraModel
{    
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public int ViewId { get; set; }

    public Guid ViewGuid { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ViewNum { get; set; }

    public int LayoutID { get; set; }

    public List<CameraViewItemModel> CameraViewItems { get; set; }
}
```

The CameraViewItemModel class is like this:

```
public class CameraViewItemModel
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public Guid ViewGuid { get; set; }
    public int ViewID { get; set; }
    public int CamNum { get; set; }
    public Guid ChannelGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ActionType Action { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am assigning the list of CameraViewItemModel like this:

```
// get all the cameramodel's
cameraModels = _unitOfWork.Context.CameraViews.Where(m => m.JobId == siteId)
                   .Select(m => new CameraModel
                   {
                     JobId = m.JobId,
                     ViewId = m.ViewId,
                     ViewGuid = m.ViewGuid,
                     Name = m.Name,
                     ViewNum = m.ViewNum,
                     LayoutID = m.LayoutId
                   }).ToList();

// get all the cameraviewitemmodels
cameraViewItemModels =

(from cameraView in _unitOfWork.Repository<CameraViews>().Get(x => x.JobId == siteId).Result
 join cameraViewItem in _unitOfWork.Repository<CameraViewItems>().Get(x => x.JobId == siteId)
 .Result on cameraView.ViewId equals cameraViewItem.ViewId into CameraViewItemResults
 from cameraViewItemResult in CameraViewItemResults.DefaultIfEmpty()

 join cameraChannel in _unitOfWork.Repository<CameraChannels>().Get(x => x.JobId == siteId)
 .Result on (cameraViewItemResult == null ? new Guid() : cameraViewItemResult.ChannelGuid) equals cameraChannel.ChannelGuid into CameraChannelResults
 from cameraChannelResult in CameraChannelResults.DefaultIfEmpty()

 select new CameraViewItemModel
 {
   JobID = cameraView.JobId,
   ViewID = cameraView.ViewId,
   ViewGuid = cameraView.ViewGuid,
   CamNum = cameraViewItemResult.CamNum,
   ChannelGuid = cameraChannelResult.ChannelGuid,
   Name = cameraChannelResult.Name
 }).ToList();

// then do a 'join' on JobId, ViewId and ViewGuid and assign the list of cameraviewitemmodels to cameraModels.

foreach (var cameraModel in cameraModels)
{
  cameraModel.CameraViewItems = (from cameraViewItem in cameraViewItemModels
                                 where cameraModel.JobId == cameraViewItem.JobID
                                 && cameraModel.ViewId == cameraViewItem.ViewID
                                 && cameraModel.ViewGuid == cameraViewItem.ViewGuid
                                 select cameraViewItem).ToList();
}

return cameraModels;
```

There are three tables in database:

`CameraViews`, `CameraViewItems`, `CameraChannels`.

`CameraViews` is the main table. It is left joined with `CameraViewItems` and `CameraChannels` to get the desired result. There may not be any data in `CameraViewItems` and `CameraChannels` for a corresponding CameraView.

Is it possible to assign the list of `CameraViewItemModels` to `CameraModels` in a single linq statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to add values to a sub list, dunno if this is what you mean. You can keep selecting sub lists if that is necessary.

```
var parent_lst = new List<List<string>>(); // Root/parent list that contains the other lists
var sub_lst = new List<string>(); // Sub list with values

var selected_parent_lst = parent_lst[0]; // Here I select sub list, in this case by list index
selected_parent_lst.Add("My new value"); // And here I add the new value
```